# Require a parent attribute when a child is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Contact with an attribute name (along with others). When contact records are created they are mostly created with the name attribute left as null. This needs to be permitted.
My Contact class has an association to WaitListMembers

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :waitlist_members
  # ...
end

class WaitlistMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  # ...
end
```

When a WaitlistMember is created I now need to impose a validation on Contact that the name not be blank.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Module#delegate` to delegate the method call to contact:

```
class WaitlistMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  delegate :name, to: :contact, prefix: true
  validates :contact_name, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a validates associated on the contact, then on the contact itself use a lambda or if with a method to apply the validation conditionally on waitlist_members.any?

```rb
Class Contact
  #...
  validates :name, presence: true, if: ->(contact) { contact.waitlist_members.any? }
end

Class WaitlistMember
  #...
  validates_associated :contact
  #...
end
```

Comment: I like this approach, however it seems due to the order of the ActiveRecord callbacks it is possible to create a WaitlistMember for a Contact that does not have a name and this is explicitly what I am trying to avoid.